# Removing needs-lock attribute when tagging

Tags: svn

I wonder if there is a smart way to remove the needs-lock attribute when branching/tagging a Subversion directory.

It comes useful because while in the trunk you need to serialize access to shared files, when you are making modifications only to a branch to integrating some trunk modifications, you are probably the only developer assigned that task.

Is there a smart way to either ignore the svn:needs-lock property during tagging (probably not) or possibly remove at once any svn:needs-lock attribute recursively in a directory?

Thank you